# Linux 2.6.23 (VM) cannot install usb wifi

Tags: debian, wifi, kde, firmware

I've just installed KDE 3.5 and am trying to get drivers working for my Atheros 9271, when I type `lsusb` it is detected but not ifconfig (only ethernet and loopback).

I have tried following instructions here:

https://wiki.debian.org/ath9k_htc

But when I run `apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-atheros` it just comes up with:

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firmware-atheros is a non free program , you should edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` as follow (do not use the redirector httpredir):

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

save and install the package:

```
apt update
apt install firmware-atheros
```

Solving this error:

```
E: The package firmware-atheros needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it
```

Try the following command :

```
apt install --reinstall firmware-atheros
```

If you still get the "half configured package" , backup your `/var/lib/dpkg/status`:

```
cp  /var/lib/dpkg/status status.bak
```

Open the `status` file:

```
nano /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

found the `firmware-atheros` then remove it with its description , save the file and run:

```
dpkg --configure -a
apt update
apt install firmware-atheros
```

The GPG error can be solved by installing the `debian-archive-keyring` and `debian-keyring`:

```
apt install debian{$1,-archive}-keyring
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, I have just updated my sources with them pasted at the bottom and then ran apt-get install and then apt-get install firmware-atheros and it returned:

Reading package lists...Done
E: The package firmware-atheros needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: @LangdonBrock See my edit , please.

Comment: I managed to complete the instruction to search for firmware-atheros and delete, save and run dpkg --configure -a, when I try the next two lines, some errors show up saying Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debia/dists/jessie/ and then quite a few lines after that with different locations, it says W: GPG error: http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release: the following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available. Then when I try and run apt-get install firmware-atheros, it says Couldn't find package, could it be that it's not downloading this package?

Comment: @LangdonBrock run `apt install debian{$1,-archive}-keyring`